# sending a javascript value to php with xmlhttp

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

i'm working on a little slider which provides a value that i want to use in php.. 
Now i've got the slider working it's storing its value in (var singleValues) but now i don't know how to send it correctly to php.

the slider:

```
function displayVals() {

        $( "#slider" ).slider();

        var step = $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "step" );

        $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "step", 20 );  

        var singleValues = $('#slider').slider('value');
        $("p.value1").html(singleValues); 

        $( "#slider" ).slider({
            change: function(event, ui) {displayVals();}
        });

    };
```

I have used xmlhttp before like down here V, but i don't know how to alter it to send (var singleValues) to a file.php

```
function achterpaneel(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("rightColumn_content").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("rightColumn_content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getAchterpaneel.php?r="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Probably it's quite simple but I can't figure it out. stil have to learn a lot:)

Thanx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the press! :P

Got it working.. used the xmlhttp to set (r as "singleValues") which i then put in a variable in the php file like this ==> $r=$_GET["r"];

So this is what it turned out to be. If anyone has a better solution let me know :) This woks fine for me :D

```
 function slider2() {

        $( "#slider2" ).slider();

        var step = $( "#slider2" ).slider( "option", "step" );

        $( "#slider2" ).slider( "option", "step", 20 ); 

        var singleValues = $('#slider2').slider('value');
        $("p.value2").html(singleValues); 

        $( "#slider2" ).slider({
            change: function(event, ui) {slider2(); ValueToPhp();}
        });

                        if (singleValues=="")
                      {
                      document.getElementById("rightColumn_content").innerHTML="";
                      return;
                      } 
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                      }
                    else
                      {// code for IE6, IE5
                      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                      }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                      {
                      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        {
                        document.getElementById("rightColumn_content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                      }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","ValueTest.php?r="+singleValues,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();


    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this line

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getAchterpaneel.php?r="+str,true);
```

is sending a GET request and concatinates `str` to the request string, my guess would be to transform `singleValues` (which is JSON, I assume) to a query string and give this query string to the function call of `achterpaneel` - depending where you have to/want to call this method.

But: Ever heard of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

Comment: +1 for the mention of jQuery. I do NOT know why anyone is doing ajax any other way anymore. jQuery's ajax functions are much less code and much more flexible and compatible among browsers.

Comment: so im doing stupidly much ajax on a jQuery slider, if i try it the way i sugested :P but is there an easy jQuery way to send the singleValues to php?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you use jQuery
you can just use

```
$.get('url.php',{slider:$('#slider').slider('value')})
```

Comment: So this sends the value to 'url.php' ?? and in php i could use something like:  `$ValueSlider1=$_GET["value"];` ?? thanx for the help!